# Fundamental unit

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let K is a cubic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$  having only one real embedding in $\Bbb{R}$, then can we find  fundamental unit in the ring of integers which is real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can. We have Dirichlet's unit theorem, stating that the group of units is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{r+s-1}\times T$, and here we have $r=s=1$, with $3=n=r+2s$, so that the group is $\mathbb{Z}\times T$, where $T$ is the torsion subgroup, which is isomorphic to $\mu_K=\{\pm 1 \}$ here. We can chose a real generator of the infinite cyclic group, i.e., a real fundamental unit.